# Comparing 2 multi-lined strings

Tags: java, c#, vb.net, algorithm, function

I am working on an application and I would like (if possible) to be able to compare 2 strings that are multi-lined.

For example:

```
string1=
001000
000100
000100

string4=
10001000
00100100
00000100

string2=
10
01
01

string3=
010
010
010
```

Output:

```
string1.contains(string2)   > true
string1.contains(string3)   > false
string4.contains(string2)   > true
string4.contains(string3)   > false
```

I need a function that is able to see that string1 contains string2.
I have experimented but have yet to find an answer that met my needs. I need it to be able to see that it contains the string where the lines are relative to each other (e.g string1 must have 10 on one line and 01 directly under it and so on..)

If the function is possible then it should return true for "string1 contains string2) and false for "string 1 contains string3",

Any help you can give would be greatly appreciated. (please use VB, C# or similar for example codes if possible)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Including or excluding the `CRLF`?

Comment: For each string in multiline counted separately for the contains part? We need an example of the return expectations with your example.

Comment: It doesn't have to look for the CRLF at the end of the line if that's what you mean?

Comment: ill edit it with the returns for my example.

Comment: Set a maximum line length, and pad with 0 on each line until they are the maximum length.  Then compare line by line.

Comment: I dont think that would work as the 0's arnt always gonna be 0's.. i updated the question with a better example.

Comment: I don't understand how `string1` contains `string2` please double check you assignments above - they are out of order.

Comment: If you reordered the characters in your strings by reversing the dimensions (ex: string1 = 000.000.100.011.000.000 string2=100.011 string3=000.111.000), it becomes a trivial substring search.

Comment: OneFineDay .. It should contain string2 because it has 10 on one line (like in string2) then has 01 directly underneath the 10 (like in string2) and another 01 directly under the first 01 (as in string2).. Im struggling to explain what i mean sorry.

Comment: Hatchet.. Your solution works perfectly for my examples. however would it work if string1 had 1 extra line at the beginning of all 0's?

Comment: `string1` does not have 10 or 01.

Comment: yes it does.. the first line contains 10 and the second contains 01

Comment: So the reason string1 does not contain string3 is that, after finding the first match, the other matches don't have the same number of characters before and after them that the first match had, correct?

Comment: what time complexity are you looking for?

Comment: In your examples, the lines in each string are all the same length. Is this always the case?

Comment: Each string will always have the same amount of character in each line. but not always the same as every other string. For example if the first line of string1 was 5 characters long then so would every other line in that string. But that doesnt effect the length of lines in a separate string. I think @Hatchet has the right idea.

Comment: @user2625752 Would string 1 still contain string 2 if string 1 was 100000 000001 010000?

Comment: @SILENT no it shouldn't because although it has the same characters in each line, they are not in the same position.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your comment on @RufusL's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29527795/2573395%20answer):

> It looks promising but i'm not sure it would work as string1 will not always be 3 lines long. But your code looks easily adaptable to make it cycle through the lines if they had different lengths :)

I am assuming that the source to be compared against, may hold more 'lines' than the to be compared string. Thus, the steps to take are basically:

1. Convert the source and to be compared strings into lines.
2. While there are sufficient candidate start lines available in the source, try to find a matching start line.
3. While a matching substring in a candidate start source line is found, check that all subsequent lines match at that substring position. If they do => match

The code snippet below provides an implementation of this algorithm in a C# extension method.

```
public static class LinesMatcher
{
    public static int CountMatches(this string source, string toCompare, params string[] lineSeparators)
    {
        // split into parts.
        var srcParts = source.Split(lineSeparators, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
        var cmpParts = toCompare.Split(lineSeparators, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

        // check until candidate first matching source lines have been exhausted.
        var matchCount = 0;
        var startLineNdx = 0;
        while (cmpParts.Length <= (srcParts.Length - startLineNdx))
        {
            // search for a match from the start of the current line.
            var matchNdx = srcParts[startLineNdx].IndexOf(cmpParts[0]);
            while (matchNdx >= 0)
            {
                // Line has a match with the first line in cmpParts
                // Check if all subsequent lines match from the same position.
                var match = true;
                for (var i = 1; i < cmpParts.Length; i++)
                {
                    if (srcParts[startLineNdx + i].IndexOf(cmpParts[i], matchNdx) != matchNdx)
                    {
                        match = false;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if (match) // all lines matched
                    matchCount++;

                // try to find a next match in this line.
                matchNdx = srcParts[startLineNdx].IndexOf(cmpParts[0], matchNdx + 1);
            }

            // Try next line in source as matching start.
            startLineNdx++;
        }
        return matchCount;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
class Program
{
    public static void Main(params string[] args)
    {
        var seps = new[] { "\n" };
        var string0 = "00000010\n001000\n000100\n000100";
        var string1 = "001000\n000100\n000100";
        var string4 = "10001000\n00100100\n00000100";
        var string2 = "10\n01\n01";
        var string3 = "010\n010\n010";

        Console.WriteLine(string1.CountMatches(string2, seps));
        Console.WriteLine(string1.CountMatches(string3, seps));
        Console.WriteLine(string4.CountMatches(string2, seps));
        Console.WriteLine(string4.CountMatches(string3, seps));
        Console.WriteLine(string0.CountMatches(string2, seps));
    }
}
```

Comment: Worked perfectly when I tested it.. Thanks!

Comment: Is there a way that your code can be edited to count the occurrences that it finds. For example if string1="001000\n000100\n000100\n001000\n000100\n000100"
and you executed "string1.ContainsAllOf(string2,seps)" it would return 2 as it contains 2 lots of string2.. ?

Comment: Yes that's pretty easy, instead of stopping and returning `true` when a match is found, just increment a counter for the number of matches found. I'll update the answer to do this.

Answer (score 0):

I've just implemented it in Groovy (tried not to use some Groovy-specific syntax).
Here's Gist: https://gist.github.com/s0nerik/9c52175dcd68ad8807b8

My solution assumes that both strings have the same height (lines number) and each line within every string has the same length. Also it assumes that every line of the first string has greater or equal length compared to the second string.

Comment: You should also include your code in your answer here.

Answer (score 0):

You could write an extension to the `string` class to do it:

```
public static class StringExtensions
{
    public static bool MultiContains(this string source, string compare)
    {
        if (source == null) return compare == null;
        if (compare == null) return false;

        var sourceParts = source.Split('\n');
        var compareParts = compare.Split('\n');

        if (sourceParts.Length != compareParts.Length) return false;

        // Try to get a match with the first pair of strings
        int firstMatchIndex = sourceParts[0].IndexOf(compareParts[0]);

        // If we didn't find any matches in the first pair, return false
        if (firstMatchIndex == -1) return false;

        // If there are no other matches to be compared, return true
        if (sourceParts.Length == 1) return true;

        var matched = false;

        // Otherwise, see if all compare matches are at same position
        while (!matched && firstMatchIndex > -1)
        {
            for (int i = 1; i < sourceParts.Length; i++)
            {
                // See if we have a match in the same position as the first match
                matched = sourceParts[i].IndexOf(compareParts[i], 
                    firstMatchIndex) == firstMatchIndex;

                if (!matched)
                {
                    // If one of the strings didn't match in the same position, 
                    // try to find another match in the first lines
                    firstMatchIndex = sourceParts[0].IndexOf(compareParts[0], 
                        firstMatchIndex + 1);

                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        return matched;
    }
}
```

And then the usage would look like:

```
public static void Main()
{
    var string1 = "001000\n000100\n000100";
    var string4 = "10001000\n00100100\n00000100";
    var string2 = "10\n01\n01";
    var string3 = "010\n010\n010";

    Console.WriteLine(string1.MultiContains(string2));
    Console.WriteLine(string1.MultiContains(string3));
    Console.WriteLine(string4.MultiContains(string2));
    Console.WriteLine(string4.MultiContains(string3));
}
```

Output:

> True
>   False
>   True
>   False

Comment: Can you assume the comparison string have the same number of lines?

Comment: It looks promising but i'm not sure it would work as string1 will not always be 3 lines long. But your code looks easily adaptable to make it cycle through the lines if they had different lengths: )

Comment: @SILENT I am enforcing it, not assuming it. Not sure I understand what you are saying?

Comment: @user2625752 Nothing is assuming string1 (or any string) is 3 lines long, however I am enforcing the comparison string has the same number of lines as the source string.

Comment: Added a fix for cases where the source and comparison strings only contain one line...

Comment: @RufusL if string 1 contained more lines than string 2 and string 2's match started on line 2 of string 1, your program would fail even though it should pass.

Comment: @SILENT oh, I see what you mean. Didn't realize that was a requirement based on the samples and description.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Sub Main()
    Dim string1 = String.Join(vbCrLf, "001000", "000100", "000100")
    Dim string4 = String.Join(vbCrLf, "10001000", "00100100", "00000100")
    Dim string2 = String.Join(vbCrLf, "10", "01", "01")
    Dim string3 = String.Join(vbCrLf, "010", "010", "010")

    Console.WriteLine("String1 contains String2 {0}", string1.ContainsPattern(string2))
    Console.WriteLine("String1 contains String3 {0}", string1.ContainsPattern(string3))
    Console.WriteLine("String4 contains String2 {0}", string4.ContainsPattern(string2))
    Console.WriteLine("String4 contains String3 {0}", string4.ContainsPattern(string3))
    Console.ReadKey()
End Sub

<Extension> Function ContainsPattern(target As String, pattern As String) As Boolean
    Dim lines = Split(target, vbCrLf)
    Dim patternLines = Split(pattern, vbCrLf)

    If lines.Count <> patternLines.Count Then
        Throw New ArgumentException("Line counts differ")
    End If

    If patternLines.First.Length > lines.First.Length Then
        Throw New ArgumentException("Pattern exceeds target")
    End If

    Dim match = False
    For m = 0 To (lines.First.Length - patternLines.First.Length)
        match = True
        For l = 0 To lines.Count - 1
            If Not lines(l).Substring(m).StartsWith(patternLines(l)) Then
                match = False
                Exit For
            End If
        Next
        If match = True Then
            Return True
        End If
    Next

    Return False
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

The best thing to do is to take your strings as one string.
And then create a function which checks the amount of numbers in your string.
The second parameter to your function which you should give,
is the amount of numbers where you get an linebreak.

Then an easy divide can check how many rows it should be automatically.
Something like this:

```
Module Module1

    Sub Main()

        Dim string1 As String = "001000000100000100"

        Dim string2 As String = "100101"

        Dim string3 As String = "010010010"
        Dim string4 As String = "100010000010010000000100"


        Dim string1Split As List(Of String) = SplitUp(string1, 6)
        Dim string2Split As List(Of String) = SplitUp(string2, 2)
        Dim string3Split As List(Of String) = SplitUp(string3, 3)
        Dim string4Split As List(Of String) = SplitUp(string4, 8)

        For Each x As String In string1Split
            Console.WriteLine("string1 " + x)
        Next
        For Each x As String In string2Split
            Console.WriteLine("string2 " + x)
        Next
        For Each x As String In string3Split
            Console.WriteLine("string3 " + x)
        Next
        For Each x As String In string4Split
            Console.WriteLine("string4 " + x)
        Next

        Console.ReadLine()

    End Sub

    Public Function SplitUp(number As String, linebreak As Integer) As List(Of String)

        Dim numberLength As Integer = number.Length
        Dim timesToGo As Integer = numberLength \ linebreak


        Dim listwithStrings As New List(Of String)


        For a As Integer = 1 To timesToGo

            Dim value1 As String = number.Substring(0, linebreak)
            Dim value2 As String = number.Substring(linebreak)
            listwithStrings.Add(value1)
            number = value2
        Next



        Return listwithStrings


    End Function


End Module
```

The last thing which you should do is take a line of a list (one row of digits)
and compare it to another line of a row from another list.
if two or more digits match then hold the digit where the match start.
Then use that digit to check both the third rows from the 2 list.

can you follow ? xD

Answer (score 0):

Try this. I think I covered most if not all situations:

```
    const char stringSplit = '\n';
    public static bool contains(this string s, string cmp)
    {
        var t0l = s.IndexOf(stringSplit);
        var c0l = cmp.IndexOf(stringSplit);

        var d = t0l - c0l;
        if (t0l == -1 || c0l == -1 || d < 0)
            return false;
        var tc = s.Replace(stringSplit.ToString(), "");
        var cs = cmp.Split(stringSplit);
        string regS = "";
        foreach (var c in cs)
        {
            if (regS == "")
                regS = c;
            else
                regS += ".{" + d + "}" + c;
        }
        return Regex.IsMatch(tc, regS);
    }
```